# Suppress RestKit Error Message

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Using RestKit 0.20.x I am firing off a series of API calls on a particular view.  If the user sends the app to the background I am cancelling ALL API calls using the following statement in the app delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

    [self.weatherManager.restKitManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

When the app returns from the background a UIAlert is visible with the following message:

The operation could not be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 2).

I don't want the user to have to see or dismiss this message upon return but am having trouble figuring out where/how to suppress this message.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was avoiding the use of `cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod: matchingPathPattern:` because I had found a post on Google Groups from Blake Watters suggesting the use of the `cancelAllOperations` method on the operation queue which did not require a pathPattern

However If I use

```
[self.weatherManager.restKitManager cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern:@"/"];
```

by specifying a path pattern of just a "/" this seems to do the trick.